# how do I paste the text currently in the clipboard into the terminal opened inside vim by using the command :terminal

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, vim, clipboard, paste

I have recently started using vim and opened the terminal using :terminal command in vim but I am not being able to paste the text in the clipboard in it. Can someone guide me on how to do it. It would be really helpful ....

Comment: How are you trying to paste?

Comment: Which Linux distro and release number are you using?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54734173/how-to-copy-and-paste-in-vims-terminal-mode) help?

Comment: Broadsworde's idea worked, Thanx a lot everyone.